# Integrating $\int \frac{dx}{1+\frac{a}{x}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

First-year problem:

How do I integrate

> $$ \int \frac{dx}{1+\frac{a}{x}}? $$

My guess is $u$-substitution, or partial fractions, but nothing that I try seems to work...

Comment: Can you show some of your attempts? This will make it easier to see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{1+a/x}&=\int\frac{x\,dx}{x+a}\\[1em]
&=\int\left(1-\frac{a}{x+a}\right) dx\\[1em]
&=x-a\ln |x+a|+C
\end{align*}

Comment: @MichaelHardy That "edit" really didn't seem worth it. You may as well make it more substantial/clearer by adding more space between equivalences.

Comment: It only took a couple of seconds and made the thing look civilized. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sure--I just think it's a little odd to take it upon yourself to edit a fairly high-rep user's answer like that, but it's nothing worth fussing over too much. Mario can obviously do whatever he wants. Out of curiosity...what is the rationale behind ending a lot of your comments with `{}\qquad{}`?

Comment: @MagicMan : That last thing as mainly aesthetic, including serving the practical interest of legibility in some cases.  I'm separating the dash that always appears after a comment from the actual comment. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots$ and $x\,dx$ is more readily legible than $xdx$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\frac1{1+\frac ax}=\frac x{x+a}=1-\frac a{x+a}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Multiply both numerator and denominator by $x$ to rewrite the integral as
$$\int \frac{x \,dx}{x + a}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+\frac{a}{x}}=\int \frac{x}{x+a}dx=\int \left( \frac{x+a}{x+a}-\frac{a}{x+a}\right)dx=\int \left( 1-\frac{a}{x+a}\right)dx$$

Can you continue?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+a/x}=\int \frac{x\,dx}{x+a}$$ and set $u=x+a$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \int \frac{dx}{1+a/x}=\int \frac {x\,dx}{x+a}\,dx$$ Now let $u = x+a$, $du=dx$ and $x = u-a$. This gives you $$\begin{align}\int \frac{(u-a)\,du}{u} & = \int\left(1 - \frac au\right)\,du\\ & = u - a\ln|u| + C \\ &= (x+a)- a\ln|(x+a)| + C \\ &= x-a\ln|x+a|+c\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just consider :

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{x}} = \frac{x}{a+x}=\frac{-a + a +x}{a+x} = 1 - \frac{a}{a+x} $$

So the integral is :

\begin{eqnarray}
\int \frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{x}} &=& \int dx - a\int\frac{dx}{a+x}
\\
&=& x - a ln(a+x) 
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Obseve that

\begin{equation*}
\int (1-\frac{a}{a+x})dx\\
=-a\int\frac{1}{u}du+\int 1dx
\end{equation*}

by using the substitution $u=a+x.$ Then

\begin{equation*}
x-a\log(u).
\end{equation*}

Substitute back to get

\begin{equation*}
x-a\log|a+x|+C.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Surely you mean $\log|a+x|$ not $\log(a+x)$.

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks for that.